# Uploading image to folder and imagepath to database

Tags: php, sql, file-upload

I have currently got imagepaths stored within the database and image files stored in a folder which corresponds to each imagepath.

I got an admin section within my website and I am considering the ability to an admin user to upload an image. What do you advice? Is it possible to upload an image file to a folder as well as storing the image path into the database?

If I was to do it like that, how do I make it so that the image path uploaded to the database is the same as the other imagepaths (as in the same directories) except for the actual name part of the imagepath.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible. What script have you tried?

Comment: I suggest you read this great tutorial about that: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php - in addition, instead of: `$target_path = "uploads/";` you could use your own $target_path from the SQL database or from your form. Als in processing the form, you could save the final $target_path to you SQL. Edit: maybe this tutorial will help to: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at a previous script i did here, it will be helpfull. Let me know if you have issues with it. Thanks

http://pastebin.com/eevUcb2f

Comment: Please do and give a feedback.
Thanks